# Casting a variable of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' to UnsafeMutablePointer<> in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, core-audio

Starting with a class definition as follows:

```
class Player {
    var playbackFile: AudioFileID? = nil
    var packetPosition: Int64 = 0
    var numPacketsToRead: UInt32 = 0
    var packetDescs: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>? = nil
    var isDone = false
}
```

Then defining a callback function:

```
let AQOutputCallback: AudioQueueOutputCallback = {(inUserData, inAQ, inCompleteAQBuffer) -> () in
   let aqp = UnsafeMutablePointer<Player>(inUserData).pointee // this gives an error

// more code
}
```

This results in an error on the second line: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' with an argument list of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?'

How do I properly cast from type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer' in Swift 3?

Comment: `assumingMemoryBound(to:)`.  Raw pointers are not to be "cast between" as in C.

Comment: The following worked: ' let aqp = inUserData!.assumingMemoryBound(to: Player.self).pointee'. Thank you.

Comment: @BDWild Don't modify the question to show the answer: _answer_ the question (as an answer). Answering your own question is perfectly fine. In 48 hours you can even _accept_ your own answer.

Comment: Got it. Still learning the protocol here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following modification eliminated the error:

```
let aqp = inUserData!.assumingMemoryBound(to: Player.self).pointee
```

Answer (score 1):

to convert MutableRawPointer to object, we use fromOpaque api

```
/// Unsafely turns an opaque C pointer into an unmanaged class reference.
///
/// This operation does not change reference counts.
///
///     let str: CFString = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue()
///
/// - Parameter value: An opaque C pointer.
/// - Returns: An unmanaged class reference to `value`.
public static func fromOpaque(_ value: UnsafeRawPointer) -> Unmanaged<Instance>
```

example:

```
var info:UnsafeMutableRawPointer = ....
let obj = Unmanaged<$AnyObject>.fromOpaque(info).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Comment: To anyone that comes across this, please refrain from using the `Unmanaged` API for this unless you need to control the ref counts of the pointer values (which is pretty much never).  There are sanctioned, typesafe solutions.